# not getting all the ranges in distribution table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i have a table which i will use to show distribution curve
so table columns are as below .

```
Emp_Dept , Salary_Bucket , Emp_in_range  
finance      10K-15K         45%
Finance      15K-25K         40%
Finance      25K-30K         15%
HR           25K-30K         100%
```

So here the issue when i am selecting data from finance department then it shows all the 3 buckets
but when we select HR department then it shows only 1 salary bucket but as per the requirement
we need all the 3 buckets and in the other Buckets  *Emp_in_range*   will be 0%
Is there a way to show other 2 rows as well for HR department with remaning salary buckets like
output should be

```
Emp_Dept , Salary_Bucket , Emp_in_range  
finance      10K-15K         45%
Finance      15K-25K         40%
Finance      25K-30K         15%
HR           25K-30K         100% 
HR           10K-15K         0%
HR           15K-25K         0%
```

can i try with CTE . i have tried case statements but those are not working . Please help

Comment: If you post the code you tried & what issues you had with it, someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dimension tables for Emp_Dept and Salary_Bucket, then it would be better to use them. Anyway I think that kind of query could help you to get desired output:

```
select Emp_Salary.Emp_Dept, Emp_Salary.Salary_Bucket, ifnull(m.Emp_in_range,'0%') as Emp_in_range  
  from (
        select Emp_Dept,Salary_Bucket      
          from (select distinct Emp_Dept from your_table) Emp_Dept 
          join (select distinct Salary_Bucket from your_table) Salary_Bucket
            on 1 = 1
       )Emp_Salary -- you can use dimension tables instead of this
  left
  join your_table m
    on Emp_Salary.Emp_Dept = m.Emp_Dept and Emp_Salary.Salary_Bucket = m.Salary_Bucket
```